# 3 different queries from 2 tables

Tags: mysql, relations

I have three tables (palettes, boxes, layout) with sample values:

**Palettes**

```
|ID_P|sign|
|   1|  P1|
|   2|  P2|
|   3|  P3|
|   4|  P4|
```

**Boxes**

```
|ID_B|sign|
|   1|  B1|
|   2|  B2|
|   3|  B3|
|   4|  B4|
```

**Layout**

```
|ID_L|ID_P|ID_B|
|   1|   1|   1|
|   2|   2|   2|
|   3|   2|   3|
|   4|   3|   4|
|   5|   4|   4|
```

So I can have 3 cases:

1. One palete with one box (ID_L = 1)
2. One palette with more than one boxes on it (ID_L = 2,3)
3. One big box on more than one palette (ID_L= 4,5)

Now, I need to group it, so I need three separate queries, that will return:

for case 1: all ID_P's of 1:1 "relation"

for case 2: all ID_P's of 1:N "relation"

for case 3: all ID_P's pf N:1 "relation"

Basically I have sollutions for case 2 and 3, but have no idea how to get case 1.

Comment: Is it a difference between `palette with strictly one box on it` and `palette with incomplete layout`?

Comment: What do you mean by _incomplete layout_ ?

Comment: I mean that single box takes only part of the palette. In fact it is incomplete 1:N layout, but numerically it is the 1:1 one.

Answer (score 0):

Using sub queries this should extract all ID_Ps which only occur in the Layout table once and then INNER JOIN them with all ID_Bs which only occur in the Layout table once... essentially returning only ID_Ps with no more than one box per palette, and no more than one palette per box.

```
SELECT x.ID_P FROM  
  (SELECT ID_P, ID_B, COUNT(*) as count FROM Layout GROUP BY ID_P) x  
  INNER JOIN  
  (SELECT ID_P, ID_B, COUNT(*) as count FROM Layout GROUP BY ID_B) y   
WHERE x.count = 1 AND y.count = 1 AND x.ID_P = y.ID_P;
```

Comment: You're using column `ID_B` whichi is not present in table `palettes`. This can't work.

Comment: The question never states it as a requirement that ID_B is in the palette table. He simply asks for a solution for: case 1: all ID_P's of 1:1 "relation" . This downvote is unjustifiable, hopefully the original poster can chime in.

Comment: *It doesn't work: [check here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=035783305039a86643575db0b854029d)*

Comment: It was a typo, `Palettes` should have been `Layout`. It works now.

Comment: I would appreciate if you could revert the downvote. This solution is readable and effective.

Answer (score 0):

Your first case can be done just by literaaly translating your request: *find all* `ID_P` *that appear once in the `layout` table, and that are associated with* one `ID_B` *(i.e. one box) in the same table*:

```
SELECT
    layout.ID_P, GROUP_CONCAT(layout.ID_L) AS layout_list
FROM
    layout
WHERE
    (SELECT count(*) FROM layout l2 WHERE l2.ID_P = layout.ID_P) = 1
    AND
    (SELECT count(*) FROM layout l3 WHERE l3.ID_B = layout.ID_B) = 1
GROUP BY
    ID_P ;
```

```
ID_P | layout_list
---: | :----------
   1 | 1
```

This can be further optimized to avoid having perform two subqueries. Given the fact that we have a `GROUP BY`, the first subquery is converted into a `HAVING count(layout.ID_P) = 1`. The second condition needs a `JOIN` to find all associated layouts to `ID_B`, and count those. This is done by means of:

```
-- Alternative
SELECT
    layout.ID_P, GROUP_CONCAT(layout.ID_L) AS layout_list
FROM
    layout
    JOIN layout l3 ON l3.ID_B = layout.ID_B
GROUP BY
    layout.ID_P 
HAVING
        count(layout.ID_P) = 1
    AND count(l3.ID_B) = 1;
```

You can see all the data, together with all the execution plans at *dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=412ffa29607cdbee5c7bd6153649f4ab)*